# How to specify more than one include directories for setup.py from command line?

Tags: python, setup.py

[Here](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/configfile.html) I found how to write `setup.py` file for compiling my own C/C++ modules for python, but I can't specify more than one include directories from command line.

Please tell me the syntax how should I specify a list of directories from command line for `setup.py`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution it should look like this

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace --library-dirs=lib_dir1;lib_dir2 --include-dirs=inc_dir1;inc_dir2
```

Answer (score 3):

The help for `setup.py` tells, you can specify multiple values delimited by ":"

Shortened output:

```
$ python setup.py build_ext --help
Common commands: (see '--help-commands' for more)

  setup.py build      will build the package underneath 'build/'
  setup.py install    will install the package

Options for 'build_ext' command:
  --include-dirs (-I)  list of directories to search for header files
                       (separated by ':')
```

Answer (score 2):

alternative option inside `setup.py`:

```
#! /bin/python
environ['CPPFLAGS'] = '-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include'
environ['LDFLAGS'] = '-L/usr/local/opt/lib1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/lib2/lib'
```

alternative option from unix cli:

```
#! /bin/bash
export CPPFLAGS='-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include'
export LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/opt/lib1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/lib2/lib'
```

fyi, I used the `environ` example to install `pycurl` from my projects setup.py after searching for a long time.